# Windows 10: how to restrict settings available to user through provisioning package?

Tags: windows, group-policy, provisioning

With Windows Configuration Designer I've created a provisioning package with only one application and the settings available to a user "Test". This is a "multi-app kiosk". There is another user "Admin" which has access to all applications.

With the Policies of Windows Configuration Designer, I've restricted the available settings to only contain "network" settings.

This work well, however, this restriction is applyed to both users Test and Admin.

Is it possible to restrict settings only for the user "Test" ?

Thanks